# Navbar fixed to top but not full-width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Using the 2.1.1 Twitter Bootstrap, I'm trying to create a navbar that is fixed to the top of the page but which is **not** full width:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I remove the navbar-fixed-top class:

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
```

to

```
  <div class="navbar">
```

then the navbar ends up looking the way I'd like it to - only 940px wide instead of full-width - but then of course it is no longer fixed to the top of the page. How can I keep this navbar fixed to the top of the page without having it become full-width?

Comment: Try to follow [this structure][1], and turn the class container-fluid to container...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559710/bootstarp-navbar-width-same-as-container/24288270#24288270

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override Bootstrap's positioning by setting it to fixed - use `absolute` if you don't want it to scroll with the page:

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0px;
    width: 940px;
}
```

(consider giving it an ID if you plan on using multiple navbars)

Comment: I had to add "width: 940px;", otherwise the navbar shrinks down to be just big enough to hold its content. Other than that though, it seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a navbar-fixed-top or nav-bar-fixed-bottom without having it become full-width and responsive to any screen size .

Step 1: add those css :(I create a css class called: `.navbar-fixed-width`)

```
@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-fixed-width {
    width: 768px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
 }
}

@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-fixed-width {
    width: 992px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
  }

}

@media all and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .navbar-fixed-width {
    width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
  }
}
```

step 2: `.navbar-fixed-width` class to navigation like this.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-fixed-width" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
         <div class="navbar-header">
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use your original markup and simply style (using the class 'navbar' to the width that you need:

```
.navbar {
width: 50%;
}

<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
```

See tutorial here:

http://www.webdesignforbeginners.info/bootstrap-simple-navbars/

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3+ should be able to handle dynamic widths for you if you wrap your navbar in a `div` with a `class` of `container` then widths will be dynamic depending on the available space.

Take a look at [Bootstrap css](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) specifically the `container` section for more details.

Comment: This only works when the navbar is NOT `navbar-fixed-top`. Applying `navbar-fixed-top` to an existing navbar (inside a container) will pin the navbar to the top of the screen and change the width to 100% of body.

Answer (score 0):

Less for Tommy Nguyen solution.

```
.navbar-fixed-width {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

  @media all and (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    width: @screen-sm-min;
  }

  @media all and (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    width: @screen-md-min;
  }

  @media all and (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    width: @screen-lg-min;
  }
}
```