# Fixed Bootstrap navbar to top of dynamic width DIV - not full width of page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, css-position, fixed

### My problem

I am using Bootstrap 3.0 and need to use a fixed navbar, which will stay at the top of a DIV on the left side and NOT extend all the way 100% of the width of the window (like I usually see Bootstrap's example do). I have some very simple code below, using ASP.NET MVC 4 which will explain the RenderSection areas.

I have included an image which shows what I am trying to do. Currently the navbar is only extending about 75% of the left side container, not the full 100% of that left side container like I want it to.

Like I said above, I want the navbar to be fixed so when you scroll it stays in one spot within that left DIV.

Any tips/hints would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

I also saw this question ([Navbar fixed to top but not full-width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571540/navbar-fixed-to-top-but-not-full-width)) but I do not want to have to dynamically maintain this navbar with a fixed pixel width in media queries. I'd prefer it to fill out the entire left side DIV that contains it.

[image: image which outline my issue(s)]
(**https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTNau.jpg**)

### My code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!--LEFT SIDE-->
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="0">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form role="search" class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </nav>    
            </div> <!--end data-spy=affix-->

            <!--the LeftSide below just contains basic placeholder text in a <p> tag-->
            @RenderSection("LeftSide", true)

        </div>
        <!--RIGHT SIDE-->
        <div class="col-md-3">

            <!--the RightSide below just contains basic placeholder text in a <p> tag-->
            @RenderSection("RightSide", true)

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Partially Solved (update)

I was able to solve my main problem that I listed above by using this bit of jQuery

```
 $(window).resize(function () {
     var w = $("#leftSide").width();
     $("#navWrapper").css("width", w);
 });
```

But this does **not** work within an iFrame.

If anyone has any insights on solving this for use in an iFrame, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's clear you've put a lot of effort into this question. A http://jsfiddle.net showing your relevant code and problem will be also very helpful.

Comment: `.navbar {width:100%;}` doesn't solve the issue for you? That should expand its width to the width of its parent.

Comment: @ChrisHardie unfortunately it does not. I double checked all DIVs to make sure no "pixel" width was on any that would be messing it up when I put the 100% on the .navbar div. I also tried to do `width: inherit` on that element to hopefully inherit of width of the column (or any parent DIV that stretched the width that i want) with no luck.

Comment: @Itay I'll try to put together a fiddle...the iFrame issue might act kinda weird so I don't know if it'll render the issue correctly. But I'll try!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing your navbar and main content area in one column and then your right sidebar in a column by itself? Then add a bit of CSS to correct for the navbar position and adjust for responsiveness.

LINK: http://www.bootply.com/ZJCGxiUD6g

Comment: Yes...see my example above & you'll see the exact same bit of code you showed here. Also this question is from Sept. 2013 and I no longer have this issue, as I don't work on this project anymore. Thanks though!

Comment: I'm not sure why you down voted my answer. Did you even check the link I provided? Whether you work on the project anymore is irrelevant to the fact that my solution does work and doesn't require the jQuery you used, as you can see in the provided link. Also keep in mind that these answers aren't just for you. The intent of this site is to have information like this available so that anybody else that encounters a problem like yours would be able to solve it in whatever way works best for them.

Comment: The example you provided did not work. I inserted a few paragraphs of text within the `col-sm-7` and then scrolled which made both columns scroll and the header (navbar) did not stick. http://www.bootply.com/oYbTks5TSC