# div class="container" not working in html page with almost no css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Inside my HTML page i use the class container. But the navbar isn't responding to this and i don't see the reason why it does this. I tried putting the class everywhere in the code but it just keeps taking all the space.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <!--JQuery-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>JK Websites & computers</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">


                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you try to put your navbar into a div.container ? like here https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

Comment: Yes, exactly the same result.

Comment: check the developer console for any errors regarding the integrity...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the class :  navbar-fixed-top.

It goes full width, here is a link to a solution and its example with your code

[Navbar fixed to top but not full-width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571540/navbar-fixed-to-top-but-not-full-width)

**example :** 
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/h2e7gpL0/)

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-fixed-width">
```

css

```
@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-fixed-width {
    width: 768px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
 }
}

@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-fixed-width {
    width: 992px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
  }

}

@media all and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .navbar-fixed-width {
    width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
  }
}
```

Dont forget to wrap your code with

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know why it isn't working. This is because Google Chrome and Chrome doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container clearfix">
```

/*into CSS*/

```
.clearfix:after{
    display: table;
    content: '';
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).